# Inconsistent padding and line height between browsers for inline sublist highlighting

Tags: html, css, layout

How do I make [the following HTML/CSS (via JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/k2d8b9vm/) look consistent across browsers?

Notice especially how different the line spacing, top padding in each cell, and position of the "NA" string are between Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="timeline">
    <h2>Trip Blog Guit Tripper</h2>

    <section>
        <h3>US Trip 2013</h3>
        <ul
            ><li class="sub-list united-states"
                ><ul
                    ><li class="status-done days-9">Seattle</li
                ></ul
            ><li class="sub-list canada"
                ><ul
                    ><li class="status-in-progress days-2">Vancouver</li
                    ><li class="category-transport train days-4">Train</li
                    ><li class="days-12">Toronto</li
                    ><li class="days-10">Montreal</li
                    ><li class="days-5 bidirectional">Quebec</li
                ></ul
            ></li
            ><li class="sub-list united-states"
                ><ul
                    ><li class="days-21">New York</li
                    ><li class="days-7 bidirectional">Boston</li
                    ><li class="days-3">Philadelphia</li
                    ><li class="days-7">Chicago</li
                    ><li class="days-6">New Orleans</li
                    ><li class="days-1">Houston</li
                    ><li class="days-8">Austin</li
                    ><li class="days-3">Los Angeles</li
                ></ul
            ></li
        ></ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS (excluding the reset), generated via SCSS, with a few comments:

```
/*container layout*/ 
.timeline {
  background: tan;
  width: 450px;
  padding: 5px; }    
  .timeline *, .timeline *:before, .timeline *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box; }
  .timeline h2 {
    text-align: center; }
  .timeline section {
    background-color: white;
    border: solid;
    margin: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px; }

  /*inline lists*/
  .timeline ul {
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    display: inline; }

  /*inline-block cells*/
  .timeline li {
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    list-style-type: none; }

  /*inner list adjustments*/
  .timeline li.sub-list {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 1px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 9px; }

  /*css country code*/
  .timeline .sub-list::before {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 12px;
    width: 18px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold; }

  /*prettiness and spacing*/
  .timeline li {
    color: #1a1a1a;
    background-color: #a6a6a6;
    border-color: #343434; }
  .timeline .sub-list::before {
    color: #4d4d4d;
    content: "N A"; }
  .timeline .sub-list {
    background-color: gray; }
  .timeline li {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px; }
  .timeline li:nth-child(1) {
    margin-left: 0; }
  .timeline li {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px; }
  .timeline li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0; }
  .timeline .sub-list li {
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px; }
```

What I'm trying to do: keep a series of cells within the document flow while highlighting certain ranges of them. I've resorted to having the lists be `display: inline` and the cells `display: inline-block`. The padding for the (height 0) `display: inline` elements is then increased to a bit beyond the cell height in order to achieve the highlight effect. Unfortunately, it seems that it's hard to get this to look right across all browsers.

Ideas on how to fix this, or to alternate approaches to solving the problem? Keep in mind that it's critical for the highlighted sections to be able to split across lines and continue with the next section.

Answer (score 0):

Well, all browsers renders CSS spacing in different ways, and there's nothing you can do about that other than targeting each browser and micro-adjust CSS for consistent rendering.

For example, for Safari, you'll use:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
/* Safari-Opera specific declarations here */
}
```

And for Chrome+Safari (hence webkit) :

```
/* saf3+, chrome1+ */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
/* Chrome-Safari specific declarations here */
}
```

and for iPhone

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    /* iPhone specific declarations here */
}
```

But the question is: do you really, REALLY, need it? As a rule of thumb, if changes aren't really important, it's better to use no hacks or special styling, after all, nobody will compare between browsers. But of course, it's your choice, if you need to do it, here you have the code

Comment: I'm normally happy to ignore such things but I definitely need the highlight to be equal around the top and bottom of the cells, and it's very obviously broken in Firefox with the highlight being so thin. I figured that maybe there was something obvious I was missing. I'm fairly new to CSS, after all.

Comment: not sure what do yo mean by highlight since I don't see any obvious highlight, but if you mean the thin grey line try adding `position:relative; top:2px;` to `.timeline li`